# trying to create a leaderboard with score and time. Local Storage?

Tags: javascript

[image]I am trying to create a leaderboard when someone completes my quiz. I can get the person to enter their name via a prompt with their score when they complete quiz. I just can get the data to stay. I think I need to store the data with storage? Or is it there a better way to do this?

I added my code to codepen since it's kind of long:

https://codepen.io/rob-connolly/pen/xyJgwx

**Edit: fixed broken codepen link**

```js
// variables

var score = 0; //set score to 0
var total = 10; //total nmumber of questions
var point = 1; //points per correct answer
var highest = total * point;



//init
console.log('script js loaded')

function init() {
  //set correct answers

  sessionStorage.setItem('a1', "b");
  sessionStorage.setItem('a2', "a");
  sessionStorage.setItem('a3', "c");
  sessionStorage.setItem('a4', "d");
  sessionStorage.setItem('a5', "b");
  sessionStorage.setItem('a6', "d");
  sessionStorage.setItem('a7', "b");
  sessionStorage.setItem('a8', "b");
  sessionStorage.setItem('a9', "d");
  sessionStorage.setItem('a10', "d");

}



//hide all questions to start
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.questionForm').hide();

  //show question 1
  $('#question1').show();

  $('.questionForm #submit').click(function() {
    //get data attribute
    current = $(this).parents('form:first').data('question');
    next = $(this).parents('form:first').data('question') + 1;

    //hide all questions
    $('.questionForm').hide();

    //show next question in a cool way
    $('#question' + next + '').fadeIn(400);
    process('' + current + '');
    return false;
  });


});

//process answer function

function process(n) {
  //  get input value
  var submitted = $('input[name=question' + n + ']:checked').val();
  if (submitted == sessionStorage.getItem('a' + n + '')) {
    score++;
  }


  if (n == total) {
    $('#results').html('<h3>Your score is: ' + score + ' out of ' + highest + '!</h3> <button onclick="myScore()">Add Your Name To Scoreboard!</a>')
    stop()
  }

  return false;
}

window.yourPoints = function() {
  return n;
}




function myScore() {

  var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "My First Name");
  if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("myScore").innerHTML =
      person + " " + score
  }
}


var x;
var startstop = 0;

window.onload = function startStop() { /* Toggle StartStop */

  startstop = startstop + 1;

  if (startstop === 1) {
    start();
    document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Stop";
  } else if (startstop === 2) {
    document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Start";
    startstop = 0;
    stop();
  }

}


function start() {
  x = setInterval(timer, 10);
} /* Start */

function stop() {
  clearInterval(x);
} /* Stop */

var milisec = 0;
var sec = 0; /* holds incrementing value */
var min = 0;
var hour = 0;

/* Contains and outputs returned value of  function checkTime */

var miliSecOut = 0;
var secOut = 0;
var minOut = 0;
var hourOut = 0;

/* Output variable End */


function timer() {
  /* Main Timer */


  miliSecOut = checkTime(milisec);
  secOut = checkTime(sec);
  minOut = checkTime(min);
  hourOut = checkTime(hour);

  milisec = ++milisec;

  if (milisec === 100) {
    milisec = 0;
    sec = ++sec;
  }

  if (sec == 60) {
    min = ++min;
    sec = 0;
  }

  if (min == 60) {
    min = 0;
    hour = ++hour;

  }


  document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = secOut;
  document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = minOut;
  // document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = hourOut;

}


/* Adds 0 when value is <10 */


function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

function reset() {


  /*Reset*/

  milisec = 0;
  sec = 0;
  min = 0
  hour = 0;

  document.getElementById("milisec").innerHTML = "00";
  document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = "00";
  document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = "00";
  document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = "00";

}



//adding an event listener 
window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ysbV.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ysbV.png)

Comment: Local storage is local to the browser. So this may be a good solution for a standalone kiosk or such, where everyone uses the same browser, but the leaderboards won't be shared by multiple people using your app on multiple computers.

Comment: That makes sense. I cant seem to find a way to keep the data static,

Comment: You need a server/database of some sort. glitch.com is a nice option for little projects like this.

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage`, as the name suggests is local - the data will only be accessible in the browser it's saved in. `sessionStorage` is also local. Generally anything that doesn't rely on a server will be local.

To store and display the data across multiple clients, you will need a server. What you need in this case is a simple back end that will provide two endpoints - one that will display the scoreboard (GET) and another that will save the data into the scoreboard (POST). There are many options you can use to create that, if you're familiar with node.js you could try express and sequelize with sqlite (if you need a database) or you could store the data in a text (CSV) file.

To retrieve the data from the web app you will need to use AJAX, if you want an easy way to make HTTP requests from JS try `fetch` - it's available in all modern browsers. Make sure to configure CORS properly on the server - this will cause some headaches in the beginning but a value of `*` for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is generally fine for projects like that.

The general flow would be like this:

1. After your web app is opened, the JS will `fetch` /scores (without any options).
2. Whenever there's a need to store a score you would `fetch` /scores/create with `method: 'POST'` and `body: JSON.stringify(scoreObject)`.

Here's an example on how to get data from fetch:

```js
async function getScores() {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/scores');
        const json = await res.json();
        // json will contain your scores
    } catch (e) {
        // Something went wrong.
        console.log(e); // Check console for more details.
    }
}
```

It may sound extremely difficult at first but once you start working on this everything will start to make sense.

---

To reiterate:

1. Make a back end and host it somewhere. Make sure to configure CORS.
2. Use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to get your data to (and from) your page.
3. Keep on experimenting, that's the best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to host the site somewhere in order for multiple users to share application state. The "Local Storage" API's are out of the question, unfortunately.

Read up on web storage API's here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

As soon as you have the need to persist data across multiple browsers and users you have now entered some fiery challenges. There's a thousand ways to solve this one. Some of the concerns to consider are:

- Security: How will you be able to securely store each users' data and know which requests come from which user?
- Storage: The data has to live somewhere outside of any individual users browser. Thus, you will need some sort of hosting.
- What about when you need to update the quiz? What happens to old completed quizzes? Will they be schema-compatible? Data migration is... lovely.

I would suggest the following study:

- Figure out a way to persist your web application data. This means you will need to either host or setup an account with a provider such as Amazon, Google or Microsoft Azure where you can host your data.
- For simple testing you can use the AJAX API's (the `fetch` thing mentioned before), or it is worth spending some time studying up on modern frameworks such as Angular, React or Vue.

If you feel the momentum while grappling with AJAX or one of the web UI frameworks, then these links might help:

https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/build-a-web-app/

https://aws.amazon.com/websites/

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/

Ultimately there are a TON of options here... these are just a few approaches to solving the problem. You can setup your own VM, you can use a myriad of "serverless" options, you can create hosted "functions" with persistence... look around a bit.

The most important thing I would suggest learning is how data is stored in backend databases for web applications. Check out the free options for some of the major services. They almost all have an option for using their services for free as long as you don't exceed monthly thresholds. Even after those thresholds are met, it's really not that expensive to have a hosted web application with some sort of database back-end.

It may sound daunting but it might be worth considering grabbing a good book on building web applications. Something using .NET Core, Python or node.js makes a reasonable back-end for API code. It really comes down to whatever you're comfortable with.

Ask some specific questions on here once you latch on to something specific and I'm sure the community will be happy to help.

Good luck!